# Implement caching for new Vimeo PHP API

Tags: php, vimeo

I have a project that was written with vimeo-php-lib which has been deprecated, so I have changed it to the new php library. Which can be found at https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

However, the old code has had caching enabled using the line below:

```
$api->enableCache(phpVimeo::CACHE_FILE, realpath(dirname(APPLICATION_PATH) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'data' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'cache' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'vimeo'), 3600);
```

How do I go about implementing it for the new API? It doesn't seem to be included in the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the current Vimeo.php library so that it will cache the results, it currently expires every 24 hours.

The _request function was modified, and two more functions were added.

```
const CACHE_FILE = 'file';
private $_cache_enabled = 'file';
private $_cache_dir = '';

/**
 * Internal function to handle requests, both authenticated and by the upload function.
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @param array $curl_opts
 * @return array
 */
private function _request($url, $curl_opts = array())
{
    // Returned cached value
    if ($this->_cache_enabled && ($response = $this->_getCached($url))) {
        return $response;
    }

    // Merge the options (custom options take precedence).
    $curl_opts = $this->_curl_opts + $curl_opts + $this->CURL_DEFAULTS;

    // Call the API.
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_opts);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $curl_info = curl_getinfo($curl);

    if (isset($curl_info['http_code']) && $curl_info['http_code'] === 0) {
        $curl_error = curl_error($curl);
        $curl_error = !empty($curl_error) ? '[' . $curl_error .']' : '';

        throw new VimeoRequestException('Unable to complete request.' . $curl_error);
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    // Retrieve the info
    $header_size = $curl_info['header_size'];
    $headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($response, $header_size);

    $final_response = array(
        'body' => $body,
        'status' => $curl_info['http_code'],
        'headers' => self::parse_headers($headers)
    );

    if ($this->_cache_enabled) {
        $this->_cache($url, $final_response);
    }

    // Return it raw.
    return $final_response;
}


/**
 * Cache a response.
 *
 * @param string $url The parameters for the response.
 * @param string $response The serialized response data.
 */
private function _cache($url, $response)
{
    $hash = md5(serialize($url));
    $response = json_encode($response);

    if ($this->_cache_enabled == self::CACHE_FILE) {
            $file = $this->_cache_dir.'/'.$hash.'.cache';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }
        return file_put_contents($file, $response);
    }
}

/**
 * Get the unserialized contents of the cached request.
 *
 * @param array $url The full list of api parameters for the request.
 */
private function _getCached($url)
{
    $hash = md5(serialize($url));
    $expire =  86400;

    if ($this->_cache_enabled == self::CACHE_FILE) {
        $file = $this->_cache_dir.'/'.$hash.'.cache';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $last_modified = filemtime($file);
            if (substr($file, -6) == '.cache' && ($last_modified + $expire) < time()) {
                unlink($file);
            }
          }

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            return json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
        }

    }
}
```